# Out of range in Color.FromArgb(Int32,Int32,Int32)

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, rgb, picturebox

I run this  code in c# language ,but there is error that

"value of "257 is not valid for red.red should be greater than  or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255"

How can I correct this error?

```
Int32[,] Y1= new Int32[width,height];//R,G,B not empty array       
Int32[,] R= new Int32[width,height];       
Int32[,] G= new Int32[width,height];      
Int32[,] B= new Int32[width,height];        
Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap[width,height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{

   Y1[x, y] = Convert.ToInt32(0.39 * R[x, y] + 0.59 * G[x, y] + 0.12 * B[x, y]);                                
   bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Y1[x,y],Y1[x,y],Y1[x,y]));
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

I know that    "Color.FromArgb(Y1[x,y],Y1[x,y],Y1[x,y])"   out of range but how can I

correct it  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to convert to grayscale. There are two things you should do:

1. Your weights are wrong. The correct weights are 0.299, 0.587 and 0.114.
2. Apply a cap using `Math.Min()`. Something like:

   Y1[x, y] = Math.Min(255, Convert.ToInt32(0.299 * R[x, y] + 0.587 * G[x, y] + 0.114 * B[x, y]));

The cap is there only to make sure our formula never exceeds the max byte value.

Comment: I also suspect that his grayscale conversion is wrong since the scales don't add up to 1.0. Wikipedia lists different values for YUV and YCbCr conversion.

Comment: @dotNET,ok but why use  Math.Min(255, Convert.ToInt32());can you explain to me please

Comment: @dotNET,yes i want to convert to gray scale first thing I can not change number  0.39,  0.59,  0.12 , Can I applay only second thing cap to make sure our formula never exceeds the max byte value

Comment: I understand cap but why use 255  "Math.Min(255"

Comment: @koki The error message you posted clearly says "... less than or equal to 255". You can use Math.Min for that purpose, but keep in mind that doing so introduces non-linear artifacts in the grayscale image.